# Como exibir duas páginas de um mesmo GridView lado a lado?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Gostaria de saber como exibir duas páginas de um mesmo `GridView` lado a lado, se possível mantendo a paginação nas duas páginas ao mesmo tempo. Por exemplo, se eu tiver um `GridView` dessa maneira:

```
Num Produto   
--------------
1   Banana
2   Abacaxi
3   Morango
4   Castanha
5   Alface
6   Tomate
7   Cebola
8   Pimentão
9   Melão
10  Melancia
Páginas: (1) 2 3
```

Ele ficaria desse jeito:

```
Num Produto       Num Produto
-------------------------------
1   Banana        6   Tomate
2   Abacaxi       7   Cebola
3   Morango       8   Pimentão
4   Castanha      9   Melão
5   Alface        10  Melancia
       Páginas: (1) 2 3
```

A paginação atualizaria as duas partes do `GridView` ao mesmo tempo, como se fosse no primeiro caso. Se não for possível usar paginação, exibir o `GridView` inteiro em duas partes já resolve o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o componente `GridView` seria mais complicado. Neste caso, você pode fazer isto utilizando o server control [`DataList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Neste componente, temos as propriedades [`RepeatDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que define o modo de exibição dos dados (Horizontal ou Vertical) e a propriedade [`RepeatColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (inteiro) que define o número de colunas para cada repetição. No seu caso, você pode setar `RepeateDirection` para `Vertical` e `RepeatColumns` para `2`e ele irá repetir do modo que você especificou, exemplo:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="2">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProduto" Text='<%# Eval("Produto") %>'></asp:Label> - 
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPreco"
            Text='<%# Eval("PrecoUnit", "{0:C}") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Para fazer a paginação, você pode implementar o componente [`DataPager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), pois diferente do `GridView`, o `DataList` não possui paginação nativa. Com ele você consegue definir várias formas de paginação, como `próximo`/`anterior`, `numérica` etc..

Veja mais como trabalhar com o `DataList` em:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525467.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/79k821wc(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Essa é uma boa alternativa. Não sabia que era possível utilizar `ItemTemplate` com outros componentes além de `GridView`.

Comment: Sim, é possível, também com o `Repeater`. Veja mais em: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.ASPX

Comment: A única desvantagem é que não é possível usar paginação nesses componentes, só no GridView...

Comment: Sim, é possível com o componente `DataPager`.